# What are the parenthesis in this piece of code for?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here is the code I am confused about:

```
const getMousePosition = (x, y) => ({
  x: x,
  y: y
});
```

I understand the arrow functions.  For example,

```
const addOne = (x) => x + 1;
```

is the same as

```
const addOne = function(x) {
  return x + 1;
}
```

What I'm uncertain about is the parenthesis that surround the brackets in the top most code.

```
...({
  x: x,
  y: y
});
```

If they weren't there then the top most code would just return an object... Can someone explain to me what adding the parenthesis will do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Advanced_syntax

Comment: because without it it would be evaluated as a block, not an object.

Comment: Fun fact: In modern JavaScript `{ x: x, y: y }` condenses to `{ x, y }`.

Comment: @epascarello thanks for sharing the documentation.  It was helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to return a JavaScript object, as in `{ a: 'b' }` as opposed to that being interpreted as a code block like `{ a(); }`.

In other words it expands to<sup>1</sup>:

```js
const getMousePosition = function(x, y) {
  return ({
    x: x,
    y: y
  });
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course `this` behaves differently as per all arrow functions.

Comment: Good answer, though  I don't think mentioning the difference in context is necessary. It might be beneficial to explain that parentheses causes the expression to be evaluated as a separate string of tokens relative to the code structure it is within.